# How do i get foundation framework javascript files to work with yii framework

Tags: javascript, php, yii, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

i am currently working on my first Yii framework project but i am currently stuck at the styling. i am using foundation framework with the styling, i have included the foundation.css and the foundation.min.js and call it on the framework which and check and it loaded well.

jquery.js
    foundation.min.js
    app.js

but the web pages is not responding. it is as if its colliding with the some other script but i can't get to know which. The foundation version is foundation 6

Answer (score 0):

I finally get to the root of the problem after much underground checks,
the foundation javascript was initialized with $(document).foundation() but i change it to $(document).ready(function{$(document).foundation()}); and it works